# Laravel: Where selection for Eloquent Eager Loading relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, eager-loading

I got two DB tables:

**Posts**

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->integer('country_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('country_id')->references('id')->on('countries');
```

**Countries**

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('name', 70);
```

I use laravel as back-end. Now I want to implement filtering data for my front-end. So the user can select a country name and laravel should answer the request only with posts that have a country with the specified name.

How could I add this condition to my existing pagination query? I tried this:

```
$query = app(Post::class)->with('country')->newQuery(); 
// ...
if ($request->exists('country')) {
        $query->where('country.name', $request->country);
}
// ...
```

... resulting in the following error:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'country.name' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `posts` where `country`.`name` = Albania)
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

whereHas method accepts parameter as per Laravel code base,

```
 /**
 * Add a relationship count / exists condition to the query with where clauses.
 *
 * @param  string  $relation
 * @param  \Closure|null  $callback
 * @param  string  $operator
 * @param  int     $count
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|static
 */
public function whereHas($relation, Closure $callback = null, $operator = '>=', $count = 1)
{
    return $this->has($relation, $operator, $count, 'and', $callback);
}
```

so Changing the code a little as,

```
$query = ""    

if ($request->has('country'){
$query = Post::with("country")->whereHas("country",function($q) use($request){
    $q->where("name","=",$request->country);
})->get()
}else{
    $query = Post::with("country")->get();
}
```

By the way above code can be a little simplified as follow;

```
$query = ""    

if ($request->has('country'){
  $query = Post::with(["country" => function($q) use($request){
  $q->where("name","=",$request->country);
}])->first()
}else{
  $query = Post::with("country")->get();
```

}

Comment: Strangely the simplified version does not seems to work in laravel 7.x. I changed it to use whereHas and its working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = ""    

if ($request->has('country'){
    $query = Post::with("country")->whereHas("country", function($q) use($request){
        $q->where("name","=",$request->country);
   })->get()
}else{
    $query = Post::with("country")->get();
}
```

Comment: Gives me: `FatalErrorException in PostController.php line 77:
syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)` error.

Comment: I have updated it. i made a mistake putting the arrow there