# Laravel with eager loading using condition

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to optimize a relationship using eager loading and implement conditions in the with clause for eager loading, however when I do the below:

```
 $totalOpenQry =  Enquiry::whereIn('staff_id', $employeeIds)
            ->with(['enquiryStats' => function ($query) {
                $query->where('is_open','=',true)
                    ->where('is_dead','=',false)
                    ->orderBy('id','asc');
            }])
            ->where('ed_timestamp', '>=', $dateRange['start'])
            ->with('country');

        $totalOpen = $totalOpenQry->toSql();
```

> $totalOpenQry->toSql()

produces the following:

```
'select * from `enquiries` where `staff_id` in (10, 15) and `ed_timestamp` >= '2017-09-12';
```

It seems to be ignoring the where conditionals in my with clause. Is there a way to fix this or implement it properly?

Thanks

Comment: Which laravel version u are using?

Comment: Relationships aren't loaded in the same query.  Eager loading still runs an additional query to load data, just not an additional query per row.

Comment: Using Laravel 5.3. @Devon, I thought I could eager load relationships using   with? My results seem to be ignoring the is_open and is_closed entirely

Comment: I recommend using Laravel Debugbar.  It will show you all the queries run.  The eager loaded query will be directly after this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`whereHas()` works basically the same as `has()` but allows you to specify additional filters for the related model to check.

```
$totalOpenQry =  Enquiry::whereIn('staff_id', $employeeIds)
        ->with('enquiryStats')
        ->whereHas('enquiryStats', function ($query) {
            $query->where('is_open','=',true)
                ->where('is_dead','=',false)
                ->orderBy('id','asc');
        })
        ->where('ed_timestamp', '>=', $dateRange['start'])
        ->with('country');
// only  enquiryStats that have is_open = true and is_dead = false are returned
```

Comment: whereHas accepts parameter as per code base  [ref link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43174190/laravel-where-selection-for-eloquent-eager-loading-relationship)

Comment: Add an explanation about what this does and I'll upvote it.

Comment: This fixed my problem. Thanks @Mr.Pyramid

Comment: yeah go for it I have added the explanation

Answer (score 1):

You'll get 2 query:

```
1: 'select * from `enquiries` where `staff_id` in (10, 15) and `ed_timestamp` >= '2017-09-12';

2 Something like: 'select * from `stats` where `staff_id` in (10, 15) AND `is_open`=true...;
```

But `->toSql()` show first only.

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding then but I need both to be the same query so that it limits my result set?

Comment: @liamjnorman Are you trying to constrain enquiries or the stats?

Comment: I'm trying to load the enquiries with related enquiryStats and then constrain the results of how many enquiries I get based on the enquiryStats

Comment: then you want whereHas in the other answer.  The conditions on with() will just constrain the results of the related data.